# Why is a DOORS Module sometimes null when trying to edit the Module via DXL?

Tags: module, null, ibm-doors

I'm new to DXL programming language in IBM DOORS. However, I think I have managed to do many interesting things: create Modules, create Objects, create Links, delete Objects etc.

However, I have a very specific problem regarding "null" Modules. I've just written null between "" because the modules exist and they are referenced with a correct name.

When doing this:

```
 Module m1 = edit("1. MY_MODULE", false)
 save(m1)
 close(m1)
```

An error like this appears:
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amkqf.jpg)

You could not understand what does that mean as it is spanish. Basically states this: "Module null parameter in the first position of the argument." That means that the "m1" is null, as the parameter for save() method is null.

The point is that it is an error which appears only sometimes. It seems that the Module is null as it has been previously opened and DOORS does not close properly.

Is there any way, any method...whatever to avoid this error?

Comment: can't you retry when you get null? DOORS is very buggy and DXL language is horrible. I wish you luck.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre tryed to do it. The problem is that it should be a way to close "opened" but "unseen" Modules...Otherwise, the problem is not really solved. Thanks for the support hehehe :)

Comment: it is very unlikely that the module has been opened previously in this same session,Of course it can happen that the module has been opened by someone else. For this case, you should use the 3rd parameter of the “edit“ perm (1. string name, 2. bool display, 3. bool silent) and after the edit, ask whether m1 is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be many reasons that the module can't be opened in edit mode. For example: User do not have write access OR Module is being used by other user, etc.
However, you can get around the error with the below code snippet:

```
Module m = edit('My_module', false)
if(!null m) {
    //execute program
    ...
}
else {
    //do something
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the script cannot find the module when another folder is active. 
Try

```
Module m1 = edit ("/myproject/myfolder/mysubfolder/1. MY_MODULE", false)
```

Comment: It seems it has improved in many times, but sometimes (even if it is in less occassions) breaks and the error appears...Any improvement?

Comment: Any hints for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56125653/why-does-doors-show-an-error-when-creating-a-new-object-in-a-module-via-dxl

Answer (score 0):

How does your script work? do you open the same module again and again and sometimes get the error or do you open lots of modules and for some of them it works and for others it doesn't? In the latter case, perhaps you misspelled the path. You could add some sanity checks like

```
string fullPathToMod = "/myproject/myfolder.."
Item i = item fullPathToMod; 
if null i then error "there is no item called " fullPathToMod
if "Module" != type i then error "there is an item, but it's not a module, it's a " type i
```

Comment: No, it is the first case. I open the same module by editing it more than once...Could be that the problem?

Comment: Well, that's unlikely. When you have a script
- edit "/path/to/module"
- do something with the module or don't
- edit "/path/to/module"

that's more or less equal to "current = m", i.e. it brings the focus of the client to the module, regardless of whether the module was changed or saved or not saved or closed.

Perhaps you get more information about the error that happens by evaluating the lastError (see noError/lastError) in the DXL manual

Comment: I have written in the next lines what is the exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Code is structured:

```
void checkModule(string folderPath, string mName, Skip list, int listSize, int listLastIndex, string headers[], string heading[], string headerKey, bool uniqueKey, string combinedKey[]){
if (module mName){
    Folder f = folder(folderPath)
    current = f
    Module m = edit(folderPath""mName, false)
    current = m
    Object o = first(m) // error sometimes: Se ha pasado un parametro Module null en una posición de argumento 1
    if (o == null){
        loadModule(m, list, listSize, listLastIndex, headers, heading)
    } else {
        updateModule(m, mName, list, listSize, listLastIndex, heading, headerKey, headers, uniqueKey, combinedKey)
        save(m)
        close(m)
    }
    if (lastError() != ""){
        print "Error: " lastError() "\n"
    }
} else {
    print "No module " mName ".\n"
}
```

}

Exactly it breaks in line:

```
current = m
```

But as said, only sometimes, not always.
BTW, I'm executing this script via Batch, via Java code. One curious thing is that if I close DOORS, and execute the script it does execute correctly. It is as if it needs to be closed in order to edit modules correctly.

I pressume **current** can be used more than once with different types of Items. I guess it should not be wrong, but it breaks saying (more or less):

> Null value passed to DXL commmand (current Module).

Obviously, it means that **m** is null, but I cannot see any reason for that.

Comment: perhaps you get more information in the order
noError; Module m = edit (...); if lastError() {print "Error: lastError() "\n"}; if null m {print "m is null, but no error occurred\n"}

Comment: I assume that you are sure that folderPath and mName have the correct values when you call the function repeatedly. Perhaps you should double check by print "->" folderPath "<->" mname "<-\n"

Comment: "if (module mName)" does not look right. Do you want to check whether you have a module at the given location? This would be done by the check from my answer May 14 13:09.

Comment: That is not a problem, it is OK, since it works with some Modules. I'm %95 sure about the problem: if a module is opened in exclusive mode, the function **edit** is not able to get the control of that Module...and it return null. Is that possible?

Comment: I have no idea how this might happen, have never seen this. Perhaps if you open many many modules at the same time and the client has no memory any more this might happen.  If you can reproduce this problem under stable circumstances, perhaps you can raise a support call with IBM.   But if this is really a problem, perhaps you can create a global skip list with key = fullName of Module and data = the opened module. With this you can use the module from the skip instead of opening the module again.