# Why does DOORS show an error when creating a new Object in a Module via DXL?

Tags: object, module, ibm-doors

I need to add occasionally Objects to a Module, depending on the needs via DXL for IBM DOORS. Only **sometimes** when trying to do this:

```
    Object newObj
    if (last(m) == null){
        newObj = create(m)
    } else {
        newObj = create(last(m))
    }
```

An error in line **newObj = create(last(m))** appears saying that the "Creation of objects is not the current Module**. It is once again strange, as sometimes appears, and sometimes not...I guess depending on the Module "status", maybe previously has not been correctly closed and editing now is impossible...I do not know what to do...Some hints?

Comment: Where is 'm' defined in your script?

Comment: It is defined in a function which calls some other function and from which Module m parameter is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what "sometimes" means. If m is not the current module, you can make it so with the statement

```
current = m
```

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but still I guess the main problem is that the Module gets ""blocked"" in a previous execution that is not finished or in which some error appear.

Comment: possible but unlikely. Which is the error message you get (please post the exact spanisch message with the IBM error number in case you get one, I think your translation is a bit misleading)